# Is there a tool that lets me share internet connection through Wifi?

Tags: networking, software-rec, networkmanager, connection-sharing

I really like OS X's ability to share the internet connection through everything within several mouse clicks, but it seems that the Mac is doing something funny that [prevents Linux machines from connecting](https://superuser.com/q/255262/10976). Is there a Linux software that lets me do the same thing, or at least to a certain degree?

For those who don't know, from Mac's internet sharing settings, you choose the interface with the connection that should be shared (in), then choose the interface(s) that should be used to share (out). The machine will then make the changes and make the connection available through the out interface(s). You can also choose a password for WEP wireless encryption. Needless to say, when done you can stop sharing.

Today I come across a [script](http://saguide.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/share-your-internet-connection-through-wi-fi/) that shares the connection through Wifi, but as such it won't be easy to enable and disable sharing, let alone changing the options. I know it's unlikely to get something as full-featured as I described for free, so please fire off all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSuSe has an administration UI called Yast that allows to setup internet sharing very easily.

http://en.opensuse.org/ICS

Other distributions should have similar tools.

Comment: Have you seen such a tool elsewhere, or do you merely think it ought to be there?

Comment: I'm not sure how far these tools go in other distributions, but Fedora and Ubuntu have some of these administration tools integrated into Gnome control-center.

Comment: You mind pointing where in the control-center?